# My WP site and password was hacked, what to do?

Tags: plugins, htaccess, security, password, hacked

Today I realized that my WordPress blog was hacked. I noticed, because the title was altered to something like:

```
+ADw-/title+AD4-Hacked By *** +ADw-meta http-equiv+AD0AIg-refresh+ACI content+AD0AIg-5+ADs-URL+AD0-http://***+ACIAPg +ADw-DIV style+AD0AIg-DISPLAY: none+ACIAPgA8-xmp+AD4-
```

After a while I couldn't login with my usual password, so I went to the host's cPanel and I tried to reset my WordPress password in the `wp_users` database, with the help of phpMyAdmin. There, I can see that somebody altered the login information to "*indoxploit*" and maybe the password MD5 hash was also altered, because when I searched it in google I got this page hit:

```
http://md5this.com/list.php?page=111459&key=1&author=ToXiC&country=Cyprus&city=Nicosia
```

Then I simply added a new MD5 hash and then I was able to login to my WP admin dashboard, I updated the WordPress version to the newest one, and the plugins too. What to do besides these actions?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to WPSE. Sorry, but [questions regarding how to recover from a hacked site are considered off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here because answering them requires in-depth knowledge of the situation at hand. This resource may be helpful to you though: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice job recovering your password, however, the exploit probably still exists so you might get hacked again.

Your next step is to find and seal up the security hole. It could be a plugin. It could be a theme.

Download and run the [Sucuri plugin](https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-wordpress.php) to help you figure it out.

Comment: I installed the original WordPress about 1.5 years ago, and since then I didn't upgraded, maybe this is why it had a security hole, or exploit.

Comment: I tried to onstall Sucuri Malware plugin, but installation fails, maybe not compatible with the newest wordpress.

Comment: What a surprise, enlisted md5sum also belongs to word "indoxploit" as password.

Comment: Running an older WordPress version certainly could've been it. Versions >= 3.7 now include [automatic updates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) which will help you going forward. Hope you got everything all sorted out.

Comment: If I download the raw access log files from cPanel, how can find the attacker's IP (and his/her POST / GET requests) ?

Comment: Finally I managed to install Sucuri plugin, and it found no malware.

Comment: I also can see strange characters in the editor: http://kepkezelo.com/images/eu14ti3rct38xqwu86od.png

Comment: Don't worry about finding the attacker's IP address. It was likely a bot and there's not much you could do anyhow. I'd completely delete your existing theme and upload a fresh copy (assuming you didn't make any custom changes to the theme's code). That's a safe way to start over.

Comment: Finally hoster support restored my blog from their backup. Then I updated everything and changed password.

Comment: Glad to hear everything is fixed now!